# logging to swing application and console + writing to a text file the result.

Tags: java, swing, log4j, logging

I have a program that can run either by a Swing Application or a Command-Line

My question is this: How can I avoid the following code:

```
String message = "performing task #1; data abcd";
System.out.println(message);
jTextArea.append(message);
stringBuffer.append(message);
```

I need those 3 lines for the following reasons:
line 1 - so I can see the console output (I use eclipse)
line 2 - so I can see the output on the swing application
line 3 - at the end, I write all the log into a file.txt

is this something that can be achieved in ONE line? (not sure but maybe a log4j?!?!, if so how?) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, just making an assumption here: the place in which you want 1 line and not 3 is where you have the line you want to write to (up to) 3 places.  So why not write your own method; you can make it static and even have it test which kind of logging to do based on application properties or whatever, then your code with the message can invoke it as:

Logger.logMessage(message)

And IT decides how many places to write it to.